# How to define access control for menu items?

Tags: joomla-3.6, acl, user-groups

I'm trying to use Joomla's Access Control List to limit the menu items in my
website.

There are mainly 5 menu items:

- Level 1 Start
- Level 2 Developing
- Level 3 Aspiring
- Level 4 Advanced
- Level 5 Elite

Level 5 can access all content(from 1-5 ).

Level 4 has access to (1-4).

Level 3 (1-3).

Level 2 (1-2).

Level 1 (Just Level 1).

I have achieved the menu control up to a certain extent by using a component called Membership Pro (with basic url controlling), but this doesn't work as it shows submenu items when entered manually.

I really can't figure out the logic for the Joomla ACL (user groups etc.).

Any ideas on this?

My site url is: http://coaching.touchtight.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on the docs page which is worth reading: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

In your case, you only need to deal with access levels, you can ignore the permissions (actions) tab.

1. You create a user group for each of the 5 user groups you have.
2. You create an access level for each of the 5 levels you have and assign the group(s) that should have access to that level. E.g. for Access Level 1, you assign all user groups, for Level 2 you assign user groups 2-5, Level 3 has user groups 3-5, ...
3. Assign the access levels to the menu items.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you with results.

Comment: This does the trick, but my other menu items disappear. For example, if I log in as level 1 user my level 2,3,4,5 menu items will not be visible. Can I change this? I really need the other menu item to be visible and when clicked they should go to a register page. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you need to make the menus public, but restrict the articles. There are also some options in the article component which may help you customise the behaviour.